# How to list all the parachains in a Polkadot network?

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

Is it possible to list all the parachains in a given network? The [documentation](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-parachains-rococo) for test-network for parachains states that we can select the desired parachain from the dropdown. I want to do the same thing from the backend using Rust but I am not sure what the cli command is (if I am running the Polkadot node) or a rust function that exists in the source code of Polkadot that lists all the parachains.

Comment: I think you'll have more success asking this in one of the specific polkadot communities, where their developers hang out. I don't think many of them are watching SO questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore here how polkadot js app lists the registered parathreads https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/page-parachains/src/Parathreads

The side menu and some other elements are built by teams adding PR with their info here https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/tree/master/packages/apps-config

And here in the paras module living in Polkadot is where all onboarded parachains are kept track https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/264b81abe854646b4f98f34b711deb0cf96f1ea3/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L563.

Comment: Hi! This is where the code live, but how do I access and fetch a complete list of parachains? And data around parachains, such as getting all the transaction volume, etc in one particular parachain?

Comment: the last link is broken, unfortunately

Comment: @AviralSrivastava I think that is a suitable question for https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions